# Rails Has Many Form in Multi Step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, form-for

Scenario is : User has many comments.

Now I have to create a form in four steps to create user and his comments.

In step 1, 2, 3 I will ask from the user to fill his profile details like first_name, email, address etc. and in the forth step there will be a button called as "ADD Comment"

When the user will click on ADD comment button a popup will open with the "Save comment"  button in that he will fill up the comment title, text etc and after filling all the information he will click on "Save Comment" button and then popup will disappear and on the same page that comment will append so row by row all added comments will be shown in the table format. Also every row will have the delete icon to delete a comment.

Now this step four is the final step that will have the "Submit" button and when user will click on that all information should be save.

How can I accomplish this task ? What is the best way to approach this ?

The ideas those I have like:

1) When user will click on next button on the third step then I can create a user and that object I can pass in the forth step to create his comments.

2) or Create both the user and comments when he click on Submit button using accepted_nested_attribute.

3) Create the comment in the database when user will click on "Save comment"

Please suggest a fully better solutions.

Thanks
Anand

Comment: You can use this gem https://github.com/schneems/wicked for multi step form

Answer (score 0):

You could create a StepsController with all your actions or I would suggest that you look at the [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) gem for creating easy multistep forms.